# Where to put 3rd party header files in your source tree?

Tags: c++, build, makefile, header-files

I have a project that uses a 3rd party library. I want to limit all code that interacts with that 3rd party library in one particular folder. Obviously, this code (lets call it Foo) needs to `#include` these 3rd party header files. And when I build that folder, I need to link it against the 3rd party `.so` file. I decided to store the 3rd party stuff in that particular folder's own include and lib directory. Like so

```
fooFolder/src
fooFolder/src/Foo.cpp
fooFolder/include
fooFolder/include/Foo.h            // would have #include "ThirdParty.h"
fooFolder/include/ThirdParty.h
fooFolder/lib
fooFolder/lib/ThirdParty.so
fooFolder/Makefile
```

My project will get pretty big. I have my own central `include` directory along with some other folders.

```
include/
include/LOTS OF FILES HERE
fooFolder/
barFolder/
```

Now say I have a `Bar.cpp` in `barFolder`, and it needs to create a `Foo` object. `barFolder`'s makefile should probably only access the central `include` directory. But, it also needs to `#include "Foo.h"`. That has 2 problems. First, `Foo.h` is not in the central `include` directory. That can be easily fixed by moving it there.

But the second problem is that `Foo.h` needs to `#include "ThirdParty.h"`. I really don't want to put `ThirdParty.h` in the central include directory since it feels messy. I want to basically quarantine ThirdParty stuff away from rest of the project.

So now it doesn't build. Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the structure that you have shown for organizing files. At compile time, use

```
-I<PROJECT_ROOT>/fooFolder/include
```

in the command line.